# Why doesn't the command do-release-upgrade doesn't require sudo?

Tags: upgrade, sudo

I was wondering why the command `do-release-upgrade` doesn't require sudo? I mean, it does significantly change your system, so I would have guessed it requires sudo.

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html#do-release-upgrade) is from ubuntu self, but it isn't that helpful. I just want to know how this is secure for the integrity for my system, if every user can access this command.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]:

I used a new terminal window, thus no sudo that wasn't expired yet, and I used the command `do-release-upgrade` NOT `sudo do-release-upgrade`.
So even with unexpired sudo I should be unable to upgrade.

[EDIT 2]:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Same happened here: do-release-upgrade and I went from 16.10 to 17.04. No "sudo" but I'm not 100% sure if I was prompted for the password somewhere after the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put simply, do-release-upgrade implies sudo in the script so you don't have to type sudo yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but how is that an good idea? Now anyone can run the `do-release-upgrade` command.....

Comment: Sure, but they can not install or upgrade. That requires sudo. All the script does is tell you if there is or is not an upgrade if you are a normal user ;)

Answer (score 4):

I just ran `do-release-upgrade` in my terminal and look what happened:

[image: do-release-upgrade]

So you don't have to worry about this anymore. `do-release-upgrade` is a python script located in `/usr/bin` which can be accessed by every user, but this script needs, as you can see, root privileges when it starts to perform actions on the system.

Comment: How comes I updated from 12.10 > 13.04, and now from 13.04 > 13.10 without sudo?
EDIT: O you are already in 13.10 :P

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen No, I'm still in 13.04. You probably entered before in terminal your password, and this didn't expired. There is a time limit in which you are not asked twice by password when you use sudo. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/14948/how-to-cancel-the-currently-applied-remaining-sudo-time-out.

Comment: I know this.
It was a clean terminal, and I didn't enter a sudo infront of the command.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen I don't think that something this is possible. For sure you used another command with sudo in front of it before to use this command or probably you was logged as root.

Comment: I was logged in as my user account, in wchich I have to sudo in order to let things change.

Comment: I had the same experience as @Dr_Bunsen: I have to use `sudo` at the start of those `apt` commands that update the system in any way, but I'm able to run `do-release-upgrade` without `sudo`, and without having to enter my password at any stage. This seems quite odd. (Note that even if I've just used `sudo`, i can't run one of those `apt` commands without `sudo`, but can run `do-release-upgrade`.)