# "sudo do-release-upgrade" or "do-release-upgrade"?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, sudo, do-release-upgrade

I see to upgrade Ubuntu to a new release version that I have to do `do-release-upgrade` which checks for the new version and allows me to upgrade. But would it not be better to do `sudo do-release-upgrade`? Would there be any difference in the outcome if you ran it with `sudo` rather than without, and would this outcome, if at all different, be any better?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360356/why-doesnt-the-command-do-release-upgrade-doesnt-require-sudo ;)

Comment: The answer to your specific question is: no, there's no reason running `sudo do-release-upgrade` is any better (or neccessarily worse) than just `do-release-upgrade`.