# How can I run Sublime Text from the launcher as root every time?

Tags: root, sublime-text

Is there a way to automatically run as `gksudo` when I click on the Sublime Text icon?

Comment: For your second question: http://askubuntu.com/q/11760/44179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update 2020-06-27: `gksu` is deprecated and has been removed for security concerns.
see [I need an equivalent of gksu in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042344/i-need-an-equivalent-of-gksu-in-18-04)

long story short:

```
sudo -H subl
```

note that the `sudo -H` is simple enough but it suffers the same security issues as `gksu`. better option (for reasons beyond my understanding) would be `pkexec`. there's also `admin://` protocol but it didn't work for me with sublime.

Answer (score 8):

Sublime Text should have a `.desktop` file located in `/usr/share/applications/` named `sublime-text.desktop`.

Open it and change the `Exec=` line to include `gksu` (or `gksudo` they are the same) at the beginning.

[image]

Now unpin and repin the sublime text icon to the launcher.

*NOTE: Your path to the sublime executable will probably be different, that's because I installed the Sublime 3 beta, don't worry about it, just add `gksu`.*

Comment: I'm using 14.04 and sublime text 3, the file `.desktop` for sublime now called `sublime_text.desktop`

Comment: didn't work for me until I realized I didn't have `gksu` installed. A simple `sudo apt-get install gksu` took care of that, and now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

gksudo - is graphical sudo. For instance you won`t see Password dialog if you run command "sudo nautilus" using Alt+F2
You may make a script (sh file)

```
#!/bin/bash
gksudo /usr/bin/<your_app>
```

Then

```
chmod +x <your scrypt.sh>
```

And then run it in Nautilus (check option "ask what to do when opening executable files" in settings)

Answer (score 2):

Like Seth said, Sublime Text should have a .desktop file located in /usr/share/applications/ named something like `sublime-text.desktop`.

You can then open it up and change the `exec=` line to include `gksudo` at the beginning, so it should now look like this: `gksudo <command already there for starting Sublime-text>`.

While this will automatically launcher Sublime text with the gksudo window, you will still have to enter your password each time, which isn't what you want.

However, what you want is possible to do, but the only way I can think of would introduce a pretty serious security risk.

You would have to turn **off** the sudo timeout, which allows basically anything to run as sudo, without your permission, which basically defeats the entire purpose of the sudo password. Check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14948/how-to-cancel-the-currently-applied-remaining-sudo-time-out?rq=1) for some possible help with that.

All in all, I know of no way to do what you want entirely safely. If you don't mind risking your system a little, it can be done via turning off the sudo timeout, but I highly recommend against that.

You would still have to enter the sudo password each time you log on, but by turning off the sudo timeout you wouldn't have to enter it again until you logged out or rebooted.

Comment: I don't mind typing my password in I just want it to automatically run as administrator. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for every time, people reading this if you want to just launch it once as root try

```
sudo subl
```

Do Not Use. See comments.

Comment: Bad idea - **never** run GUI apps with plain `sudo` - it *might* give you troubles on the next login - see problems with `.Xauthority`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus

Comment: Thanks, for correcting me.When I run gksudo subl though sublime text does not launch.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this via a Google search.  I know this doesn't answer the OP's original question, but it is for anyone that used the same query as I.

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I just ran sublimetext from the command line with gksudo.

`gksudo /usr/bin/subl`

Comment: The reason this is incorrect and the accepted answer is correct is because the question is to default the application to run as gksudo. What you wrote will work to run sublime as sudo but it will not default the app to run as sudo when it is opened via icon.