# How can I make Sublime Text 3 run as root from Unity?

Tags: sudo, sublime-text, gksu

I know I am not root because I cannot browse packages.
First, I am aware of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426210/how-can-i-run-sublime-text-from-the-launcher-as-root-every-time) page, but it is not working for me.  After following those instruction, I get the prompt when I open Sublime from Unity, but I am still not able to browse packages. If I open sublime using `gksu subl` in the terminal, nothing happens.  If I do `sudo subl` it opens and I can browse packages.  Is it OK to open sublime as sudo every time instead of gksu?

Edit: Actually, when I open sublime from Unity, it prompts for the password, then doesn't open at all.

Edit: `gksudo subl` has the same effect as gksu.  I installed Sublime from the website (clicked the Ubuntu 64 link, it downloaded, clicked the download, it took me to Software Center).  "which subl" returns `/usr/bin/subl`. gksu is installed.  Glutanimate, yes that is what I mean.  Any idea what is happening then?  I can only browse them if I use sudo.

`/usr/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Version=1.0 
Type=Application 
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor 
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose 
Exec=gksu /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false 
MimeType=text/plain; 
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development; 
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window] 
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n 
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document] 
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Comment: (Really) silly question, but you *did* install `gksu` didn't you? It isn't installed by default.

Comment: When you say "browsing packages", do you mean the ST package manager? I am asking because you shouldn't need root to browse/install/remove Sublime Text packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### When `gksu`/`gksudo` doesn't work or is unavailable, you can use `sudo -H` instead.

If you run a graphical program with `sudo` instead of `gksu`/`gksudo`, you should use `sudo -H ...` (or `sudo -i ...`) instead of just `sudo ...`.

```
sudo -H subl
```

```
sudo -i subl
```

<sup>(Neither plain `sudo ...` nor those ways will typically work from the Unity dash, because they need a terminal on which to prompt you for your password. But you can run them from the Terminal.)</sup>

The main reason it's [considered bad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) to run a graphical program with normal `sudo` is that this runs the application with its `HOME` environment variable set to non-root caller's home directory (`/home/username`) rather than root's home directory (`/root`). That often [causes configuration files that should belong to the regular user, to belong to root instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application) (and inaccessible).

Running `sudo` with the `-H` flag prevents this by making sure root's home directory is used instead.

`sudo -i` does this and more: it runs a program in a simulated root login session. I'm not aware of any strong reasons to prefer one or the other of `sudo -H` and `sudo -i`, when the goal is just to run graphical programs as root without problems.

Comment: When will pkexec grow up, so that we can skip this mess?

Comment: @muru [polkit/PolicyKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) is quite capable., but `pkexec` intentionally won't run graphical apps without polkit profiles. Usually `gksu`/`gksudo` work; even with this weird situation (that may be a bug but I don't want to rush and assume that), I don't know that a polkit way of running arbitrary apps as root would be more reliable overall. *But there is a [polkit-based `gksu` implementation](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Attic/gksu) ([README](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/utopic/gksu-polkit/utopic/view/head:/README)).*