# sublime text 3 menu not showing

Tags: 16.04, text-editor, sublime-text, file-format

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and yesterday I've installed Sublime-text-3 text editor.
But the main problem is Menu is not showing unless its opened in root mode,i.e `sudo /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text`
I have searched for various solutions in stackoverflow and askubuntu,but neither solution worked as desired.
I have referred [sublime from launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426210/how-can-i-run-sublime-text-from-the-launcher-as-root-every-time) but it also not worked. I had installed sublime-text-3 in previous ubuntu versions and also linux-mint which i had used in the past. But no-where this problem occurred.

Can anyone has similar problem OR some working solutions,please share here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I temporary fixed this by adding command to startup applications list:

```
bash -c "sleep 2 && initctl restart unity-panel-service"
```

You can also press ALT+F2 and execute:

```
initctl restart unity-panel-service
```

Ps: This will restart all indicators services and some of them will disappear if they started before.

Comment: Can i start sublime in root mode (using sudo) everytime ? Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: You need to edit sublime-text.desktop or better make a copy from/user/share/applications to .local/share/applications loacted in Your home folder. Change permissions for You make executable. Then edit with gedit and change line: Exec=gksu /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F

Comment: If "gksu" will not work try sudo -H. More info here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/517821/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-3-run-as-root-from-unity