# How to force a password request when using apt-get install?

Tags: apt, sudo, password, authentication

When I run `sudo apt-install <pkgname>`, there is no password request.

How can I enforce a password check whenever this command is run? Why isn't it asking by default? Isn't that the point of sudo? Perhaps I might have mis-configured something so that this is bypassed?

How can I ensure that a password request is issued when I run an `apt-get install <pkgname>` command?

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/14948/how-to-cancel-the-currently-applied-remaining-sudo-time-out for `sudo -k`

Comment: You might have already used sudo once. It caches your password. Does this happen always or sometimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo caches your elevated privilege for about 15 minutes  ([sudo, sudoedit - execute a command as another user | Ubuntu Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html)) It's likely you didn't get asked for a password because you'd already entered it within that time. You can change the default by editing `/etc/sudoers` by typing `sudo visudo` eg:

```
Defaults:user637251 timestamp_timeout=30
```

see:
[Change sudo default password timeout | ScottLinux Blog](https://scottlinux.com/2012/08/04/change-sudo-default-password-timeout/)

Comment: Thanks @siloko - that makes total sense! I'm new to ubuntu to this is a noob question. appreciate the fast response too!

Answer (score 2):

Normally you will run `sudo apt-get install ...` and sudo will ask for your password the first time sudo is called and cache the password for 10 or 15 minutes, so the next calls to sudo doesn't require a password.

If you run `apt-get install ...` from root prompt, it will never ask for password.

Comment: Hi @soren A I just saw your answer also. Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1):

You can also reset the time-stamp, whenever you want to execute apt-get command as below:

```
sudo -k && sudo apt-get install package_name
```

From man sudo : '-k' invalidates the user's cached credentials